# How to achieve a css pseudo-element based and transition based tab-navigation behavior and styling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pseudo-element

How can I implement a functioning tab-navigation behavior?

What I want to achieve is a underlying animated bar for each navigation-item that has been clicked.

The transition-related styling is supposed to be based on css pseudo-elements.

Below is the markup and the css-rules I came up with so far.

What am I missing in my code? How could the approach be fixed?

```css
li::after {
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom: red solid 3px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

li::before {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav_link">
    <strong>
      <li onclick="tabs('avisos')">Avisos</li>
      <li onclick="tabs('atividades')">Atividades</li>
      <li onclick="tabs('trabalhos')">Trabalhos</li>
      <li onclick="tabs('provas')">Provas</li>
      <li onclick="tabs('aulas')">Aulas</li>
    </strong>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You don't have a `content` property on your first rule.

Comment: Nothing in the code you've shown will do anything when one of the `li` elements is clicked. I'm guessing you forgot to include the JS of `tabs()` which has that functionality...?

Comment: Also, a `strong` element isn't a valid child of a list element. You seem to be using it for styling, which is inappropriate anyway.

Comment: There is lots wrong here - the only children of a ul that are allowed are li elements; the after pseudo element has no content but it also has no size nor is it clear whether it is to be positioned relative to the li or some other positioned ancestor, there is no event registered on, say, the li elements, and if that is to be done via JS and setting a class, the after pseudo element needs to have settings when the li has that class, not otherwise.

Comment: js `tabs` is another function, it would be done through `li::after`

Comment: list items should not be used as interactive elements. use a `<a>` or a `<button>` instead

Comment: @AlanPereira ... Regarding the so far provided approaches / solutions are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the provided `::after` rule there is no definition of how the pseudo-element should be **`display`**-ed in addition to the also missing `content` attribute.

And for the entire example as is, there is no need for a JavaScript based solution.

A css-only variant of the OP's code could use e.g.

- a `:hover` based approach.

And regarding the `::before`/`::after` pseudo-element based transition-effect

- `height`, in my opinion, is a more intuitive attribute to go for.

```css
.nav_link {
  width: 20%;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
.nav_link li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px 0 7px 0;
}
.nav_link li::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  background-color: red;
  transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
}
.nav_link li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nav_link li:hover::after {
  height: 2px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav_link">
    <li>Avisos</li>
    <li>Atividades</li>
    <li>Trabalhos</li>
    <li>Provas</li>
    <li>Aulas</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Due to the markup, provided by the OP, the above example does not support a behavior similar to the OP's intended script-based `click` handling.

A small markup change could solve this though and support tab navigation too.

```css
.nav_link {
  width: 20%;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
.nav_link a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px 0 7px 0;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.nav_link a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  background-color: red;
  transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
}
.nav_link a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nav_link a:hover,
.nav_link a:focus {
  outline: 1px dashed red;
}
.nav_link a,
.nav_link a:hover,
.nav_link a:focus,
.nav_link a:active,
.nav_link a:visited {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav_link a:target::after,
.nav_link a:focus::after,
.nav_link a:active::after {
  height: 2px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav_link">
    <li>
      <a name="avisos" href="#avisos">Avisos</a></li>
    <li>
      <a name="atividades" href="#atividades">Atividades</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a name="trabalhos" href="#trabalhos">Trabalhos</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a name="provas" href="#provas">Provas</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a name="aulas" href="#aulas">Aulas</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -2):

You're probably looking for `li:active` or `li:visited`
Note that when using `li:active`, the item will only be underlined while the mouse button is down.

[More here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active#:%7E:text=The%20%3Aactive%20CSS%20pseudo-class%20represents%20an%20element%20%28such,is%20commonly%20used%20on%20%3Ca%3E%20and%20%3Cbutton%3E%20elements.)

Comment: that's the point, it's to be underlined when clicked.